Vulcan failed to select physical device after passing profile checks (when trying to open UnrealEditor)?
Hawaii XT / Grenada XT [Radeon R9 290X/390X]
How can I find out what driver I have to install for this graphics card and from where? I can't seem to find the right one, can anyone help please?

In most cases a simple ubuntu-drivers autoinstall will install the best kernel modules (aka drivers) for your actual hardware. Any more requires details of your Ubuntu product & release which you've not said.. eg. switching kernel stacks maybe an option as Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack options; the default being set by install media used.

I have installed Ubuntu Version 24.04.1 LTS Noble Numbat. Can you guide me from here? I'm a newbie...

I have tried ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and it says they are already installed.

Radeon cards don't typically have special drivers outside of what comes preinstalled. If you provide more specifics about what you did, like exact commands you typed and exact output you got (copy and paste all this into your question, don't reply in comments or use screenshots) someone might be able to help. Of course your computer might just not be able to run the application.

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
